# Fast loading in jquery slideshow + slideshow type

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I'm not a professional in `jquery` but I'm learning on a site that was made and I'm trying to edit it for just learning purposes. Following is the site link.

www.egypt-online.co

I have some questions and I hope I get answers for it.

1. what is the name of the portfolio slideshow ?
2. I want to change the effect when I press on the arrow for next image to be shown like
   this

http://bit.ly/Z56izf

3- how to make images load fast because when i press on any of categories it takes some time load the image, so i was asking if there is anything to make it load faster

4- i want to add some bottoms on portofolio in which to be seen as like this

http://bit.ly/ZzazHx

I just want to know the way or the method of how these things work .

Comment: Look at the source code of the pages and learn from it. Please try it first and provide some code so that we can help with your specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

1.you are using jQuery Cycle Plugin

2.if you want to change the effect you can go http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/
  and change the 'fx' property like demos

http://bit.ly/12oMQOt

3.Because your image is large .You should optimize your image to a fast load

4 ...

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have some questions on your answers.

1- how did you know the type of the slideshow ? i mean how do i know it ?

2- I didn't get your 2nd answer is it about my slideshow "fx property " or it is about the effect that i want to add ?

3- Do you know how to get to the portfolio files or codes that controlls this point that we'r talking about ?

thanks anyway

Comment: any comment  available here ?